# Передача потока чтения из файла в функцию C++

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin, fstream

В общем, передаю поток чтения из файла в функцию, чтобы строку считала, но вадаёт ошибку:

```
char *readLine(ifstream in) {
    char *str = new char[1];

    char ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = in.get()) != '\n' && (ch != '\0') {
        str[i++] = ch;

        char *copyStr = new char[i + 1];
        strncpy(copyStr, str, i);

        delete[] str;
        str = copyStr;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';

    return str;
}

int main() {
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    char *str = readLine(in);
    cout << str << '\n';
    in.close();
}
```

Ошибка:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/garbart/Desktop/Labs/lab_6/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/cygdrive/c/Users/garbart/Desktop/Labs/lab_6/main.cpp:63:28: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
     char *str = readLine(in);
```

Как это можно исправить и из-за чего это вообще происходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь передать ifstream по значению. А это значит, что нужно у объекта in вызвать конструктор копий. Но только у ifstream конструктор копий удален - копирование данного объекта может привести к сложным багам.

Что же делать? Передавать по ссылке или перемещать (`std::move`).

то есть, либо так исправить сигнатуру

```
char *readLine(ifstream& in)
```

либо вызывать так

```
char *str = readLine(std::move(in));
```

но только в этом случае закрытие файла бессмысленно (объект то уже перемещен!) и скорее всего приведет к ошибкам. Но файл и так будет закрыт при вызове деструктора.

P.S. возвращайте в функции std::string - Ваш код сильно упростится. Не нужны все эти "сишные приседания".

Comment: Да я, знаете, и не против str::string, да только вот преподаватель настаивает на чаровых массивах - поймём, мол, лучше)

Comment: @dtcobra для "понимания лучше" напишите свою реализацию string

Answer (score 7):

Потоки ввода-вывода владеют состоянием которое теряет смысл при копировании. К примеру, для ifstream таким состоянием будет текущая позиция в файле. Если ее скопировать - то после первой же операции ввода-вывода над одной из копий текущая позиция во второй копии устареет.

По этой причине потоки данных обычно передаются по ссылке:

```
char *readLine(ifstream &in) {
```

---

PS рекомендую вам использовать алгоритм экспоненциального роста буфера для строки - потому что сейчас у вас строка читается за время пропорциональное квадрату числа символов в ней (и это еще не считая скорости выделения памяти). А еще лучше - используйте `std::string` для тех же целей.